# What can make the system impossible to debug?

Tags: debugging, gps, stm32f4

I am currently programming an embedded system, which works with a GPS modem. I do not have any problem debugging the software as long as I do not activate the GPS module.

As soon as I do it, I cannot use any break point anymore nor stop the program. If I try to do it, the software to debug (Atollic TrueStudio) writes "Starting target CPU" and nothing changes.

Note that I overtook the programming of this system, which works. I need to develop it further. I can compile it without any problem, but not debug it (even if use the same develepment tool, the same software and the same hardware).

So the problem is neither the hardware nor the software. But probably in my way of debugging (I do not think, they developed the software without seeing anything).

Does anyone have an idea, why does the activation of the GPS make stopping the debug? Do I have any other drivers, than the ones proposed by Atollic, to download?

Parameters of the embedded system:

- Microprocessor: STM32F405RGT
- Operating system: FreeRTOS
- GPS Module: RXM-GPS-RM (Linx company)
- Develeppoment tool: Atollic TrueStudio 5,6,7,8, 8pro (I tested all of them. Atollic 5.1.1 has been used to develop this software)